# mdadm device missing

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

After a reboot my `/dev/md0` device was missing. This is a RAID-1 array from two partitions of two harddrives. On each of the harddrives is another partition, which together belong to `dev/md1`. However, only `dev/md0` was missing.

`cat /proc/mdstat` and `mdadm --detail --scan` revealed both only one array (`md1`). But `mdadm -Es` showed up both arrays:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=xx
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=xx
```

Has anyone an idea why `/dev/md0` is not mapped and not identified correctly?

Answer (score 1):

To get my `/dev/md0` array back I added the output of `mdadm -Es` to my `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`. Before there was only the automatic scan with `DEVICE partitions` configured.

However I am still curious why the automatic scan misses the one array.